# Deep learning for 3d datasets, what is the best way to prepare a pipeline? and which algorithm would be best?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pipeline

So I have a point cloud or a 3D grid, each grid contains the following data (features/attributes): Grid type (building, tree, grass, soil, or blank). But then space type "Buildings" has sub-attributes such as conductivity and reflective values. Besides, the attributes of the cells there are a couple of individual other attributes that apply to the whole data set, examples of these attributes are wind speed, temperature,....etc. I would like to know what Deep learning algorithm would be helpful to predict the values of air temperature in each grid cell (in the x, y direction only) based on the 3d attributes I explained above. Also, what would be the best way to prepare a pipeline for this?. The goal is to predict  air temperate values when I feed the trained model a data set that has geometric model info, the wind direction, and the wind speed)

Here is an example image of 300 images I have ( have the images, and I have a data set of all the attributes of each grid cell, and the air temperature value). The image is modeled inside a cube of 60x60x60 cells, when a cell contains a building the space type is set to a "building", when a cell has air the space type is set to "blank" and so on...., as I mentioned, each "building" cell contains additional sub-attributes. The values I'm trying to predict are values of air temperature at each BLANK cell (around buildings) at an x,y plane (let's say at height z=2), in this image, the x,y plane is the colored plane. I have the values in numbers, not just colored planes.
[image]

Also here is a small portion of the data I have and the results (y values = air temp).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your problem is 3D does not mean your dataset have to be.

This seems to me like a very straight forward Machine Learning problem, you could reformat your data into one dateset were each rows contains : cell location (`x, y, z`), `cell type`, `sub_attribute`.... and the target : `temperature`.

The preprocessing required will depend on the kind of model you choose, some don't support `categorical` input others do.

You can use Deep Learning if you prefer, but they typically don't work with categorical variable so you'll have to encode all textual information, and 300 instances is very small to train that kind of model.
You might have more luck with a `Random Forest` algorithm as a first step.

Comment: Thanks for your input! This is great. I was thinking the same thing, that my dataset doesn't have to be 3D but wasn't sure since I'm still exploring the world ML and deep learning.